# Why a $e^{i \pi/4}$ (or $e^{-i \pi/4}$) causes a phase shift of $\pi/2$ instead of $\pi/4$ in the case of a quarter-wave plate?

Tags: optics, phase-space

Given a spinor $\begin{pmatrix} E_x \\ E_y \end{pmatrix}$, I learned that if we place a quarter-wave plate with its fast and slow axes in the x- and y-direction, the relative phase shift in the x- and y-components of the spinor is $\pi/2$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} E_x' \\ E_y' \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\pi/4} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/4} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} E_x \\ E_y \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where the unprimed fields are those entering the quarter wave plate, and the primed ones are those existing it. I wonder why the phase shift is not $\pi/4$ (as indicated by $e^{i \pi/4}$ or $e^{-i \pi/4}$ or "quarter"), but $\pi/2$ instead?

Comment: That's not a "spinor."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write the matrix as
$$
e^{-i\pi/4} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/2} \end{pmatrix},
$$
you can easily see that the phaseshift between the two components is in fact $\pi/2$. The name of quarter-wave plates refers to a quarter of the wavelength which is $2\pi/4=\pi/2$, if you consider a wave vector of length $1$: $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}=|\vec k|=1$.

Comment: Bummer - hope people come back and upvote this more detailed answer vs. JMurray's correct but limited response.

Answer (score 7):

One component is shifted forward by $\pi/4$ and the other is shifted backward by $\pi/4$, so the relative shift between the two components is $\pi/2$ (which is one quarter of $2\pi$).